# Check if the orthogonal system is complete

Tags: fourier-analysis, orthogonality

According to my lecture notes:

The orthogonal system $\sin{kx}, k=1,2, \dots $ in $[0, \pi]$ is a complete system in $L^2[0, \pi]$.

$1, \cos{kx}, \sin{kx}$ in $[0, 2 \pi] $is a complete system in $L^2[0,2 \pi]$.

$\sin{2x}, \sin{3x}, \dots, \sin{nx}, \dots n \geq 2$ in $[0,\pi]$ is an orthogonal system, **BUT**   it isn't complete, because:

If we pick $X(x)= \sin x$, the Fourier coefficients of it in respect to the orthogonal system $\sin{2x}, \sin{3x}, \dots, \sin{nx}, \dots n \geq 3$ are $A_k=0, k=2,3, \dots$

$$A_k=\frac{\int_0^{\pi} \sin{nx} \sin{kx} dx}{\int_0^{\pi} \sin^2{kx}dx}=0$$

$\sin x$ should converge to $0$ in $L^2$ norm.

$$$$

So does this mean that we have to pick a specific $X$, then calculate $A_k$ and check if $X$ converges to $A_k$ in $L^2$ norm?

I tried to show that the orthogonal system $\sin{kx}, k=1,2, \dots $ in $[0, \pi]$ is a complete system in $L^2[0, \pi]$, as follows:

Let $X(x)= \sin x$.

$$A_k= \frac{\int_0^{\pi} \sin{kx} \sin x dx}{\int_0^{\pi} \sin^2{kx}dx}=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \sin{kx} \sin{x} dx=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \left[ \cos((k-1)x)-cos((k+1)x)\right]dx$$

$$A_k=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 &, k \neq 1 \\ 
1 & , k=1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Is it right so far? Do we have to check now if $\sin x \sim A_k$ in $L^2[0, \pi]$ ? Or do we have to do something else?

**EDIT**: I found also the following in my notes.

$$f \sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x_n$$

$$S_N(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n X_n(x)$$

Definition of complete:

$$\lim_{N \to +\infty} S_N(x) \overset{L^2[a,b]}{=}f(x)$$

Could we maybe apply the above definition, by picking a specific $X$ ?

**EDIT**:If we consider the case where $f(0)=0, f(\pi)=0$ on $C^{\infty}[0,\pi]$,  how do we deduce that the eigenvalues are $1^2, 2^2, 3^2, \dots$ ? Also, in this case isn't the system $1, \cos{kx}, \sin{kx}$ complete?

Comment: $A_k$ isn't a function, what do you mean by $X$ converging to it? Do you know what it means for an orthogonal system to be complete?

Comment: @anon I don't know.. I thought so because at my notes, I found the following:
$$\sin x \sim 0$$
it should converge to $0$ in $L^2$ norm.

Comment: @anon Isn't an orthogonal system complete in a space if all the functions that belong to this space can be written as a linear combination of the elements of the orthogonal system? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of complete. What does $\sin x\sim0$ mean? What are you claiming converges to $0$?

Comment: I don't know... That's exactly what I found in my notes...
$$$$
How can we show that all the functions in $L^2[0, \pi]$ can be written as a linear combination of $\sin{kx}, k=1,2, \dots$ ?

Comment: It's not so easy to prove completeness, but it's often easy to prove incompleteness by an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical sets of orthogonal eigenfunctions come from solving the eigenvalue problem
$$
                        -f'' = \lambda f
$$
on $[a,b]$, subject to separated conditions
$$
             \cos\alpha f(a) + \sin\alpha f'(a) = 0,\\
             \cos\beta f(b) + \sin\beta f'(b) = 0,
$$
or periodic conditions
$$
               f(a)= f(b),\\ f'(a)=f'(b).
$$
**Examples:**

1. Consider periodic conditions on $[-\pi,\pi]$, then the eigenvalues $\lambda$ are $0,1^{2},2^{2},3^{3},\cdots$, with eigenfunctions
   $$
              1,\cos x,\sin x,\cos 2x,\sin 2x,\cdots.
   $$
2. Consider $0$ endpoint conditions $f(0)=0$, $f(\pi)=0$, on $[0,\pi]$. The eigenvalues $\lambda$ are $1^{2},2^{2},3^{2},\cdots$, with eigenfunctions
   $$
              \sin x,\sin 2x,\sin 3x,\cdots .
   $$
3. Consider $0$ derivative conditions $f'(0)=0$, $f'(\pi)=0$, on $[0,\pi]$. The eigenvalues $\lambda$ are $0,1^{2},2^{2},3^{2},\cdots$, with eigenfunctions
   $$
               1,\cos x,\cos 2x,\cos 3x,\cdots .
   $$
4. Consider mixed conditions $f(0)=0$, $f'(\pi)=0$, on $[0,\pi]$. The eigenvalues $\lambda$ must solve $\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=0$, or
   $\lambda = (n+1/2)^{2}$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$, with eigenfunctions
   $$
            \sin(x/2),\sin(3x/2),\sin(5x/2),\cdots .
   $$

For all possible conditions, the resulting eigenfunctions form a complete orthogonal basis of $L^{2}[a,b]$. If you leave out of one the eigenfunctions from the set, then the resulting set cannot be complete because the one you leave out is orthogonal to all the rest and, hence, a series in the remaining functions is orthogonal to the one that was omitted.

Comment: If we consider the case where $f(0)=0, f(\pi)=0$ on $C^{\infty}[0,\pi]$,  how do we deduce that the eigenvalues are $1^2, 2^2, 3^2, \dots$ ? Also, in this case isn't the system $1, \cos{kx}, \sin{kx}$ complete?

Comment: (Question 1) The solutions with $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$ are $f_{\lambda}(x)=\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)/\sqrt{\lambda}$. The set of $\lambda$ for which $f_{\lambda}(\pi)=0$ also holds can be deduced from this. (Question 2) $\{ 1,\cos kx,\sin kx,\cdots\}$ is a complete set on $[-\pi,\pi]$ because these are periodic with periodic derivatives on $[-\pi,\pi]$; these are not even orthogonal on $[0,\pi]$, even though they are on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: @evinda : It is worth further note that $\{ \cos kx \}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ is complete on $[0,\pi]$ and $\{ \sin kx \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ complete on $[0,\pi]$. That means all of the cos terms can be written as sins and the other way around. This is a strange result when you first see it; but keep in the mind that the identity will only hold in $(0,\pi)$ and not necessarily at either endpoint. But $\{ 1,\cos kx, \sin kx \}$ is not a linearly-independent set when you allow series in $L^{2}[0,\pi]$, even though it is spanning.